# Code ran on python 2.7 but gives error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str on version 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-processing

I have this Fedex Batch tracking code that gives and following error:

```
runfile('***/Fedex Batch Track/trackitall.py', wdir='***/Fedex Batch Track')
{'Ship Date': '7/22/2017', 'Actual Delivery': '7/28/2017'}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-262-91e531a602be>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('***/Fedex Batch Track/trackitall.py', wdir='***/Fedex Batch Track')

  File "***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "***/Fedex Batch Track/trackitall.py", line 55, in <module>
    evaluate_excel("trackthis1","tracking_column","output3.txt")

  File "***/Fedex Batch Track/trackitall.py", line 32, in evaluate_excel
    for x in sheet.col_values(tracking_column):

  File "C:\Users\Freight\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 531, in col_values
    for rowx in range(start_rowx, end_rowx)

  File "***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 531, in <listcomp>
    for rowx in range(start_rowx, end_rowx)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I can't figure out why.

Here is the full code

```
from track import evaluate
import xlrd
import os


def get_list(name, tracking_column):
    dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    name_of_file = dirname + '/'+str(name) + '.xls'

    book = xlrd.open_workbook(name_of_file)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    tracklist = []
    for x in sheet.col_values(tracking_column):
        tracklist.append(x)
        trackingnumber = x

    return tracklist


def evaluate_excel(name, tracking_column, outputfile):

    dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    name_of_file = dirname + '/'+str(name) + '.xls'
    outputfile = str(outputfile)+'.txt'


    book = xlrd.open_workbook(name_of_file)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    tracklist = []
    for x in sheet.col_values(tracking_column):
        tracklist.append(x)
        trackingnumber = x

    with open(outputfile, "wt") as text_file:
        #os.chmod(name, 0600)
        print('trackingnumber\tShipped\tArrived\tDelivered')

        text_file.write('trackingnumber\tShipped\tArrived\tDelivered\t')

        for x in tracklist:
            y = x
            a,b,c = evaluate(x)
            if a != "":
                text_file.write('\n'+str(y) + "\t" +str(a)+"\t"+str(b) + "\t" + str(c)+'\t')
                print(str(y) + "\t" +str(a)+"\t"+str(b) + "\t" + str(c)+'\t')

            else:
                print(str(y) + "\t" + 'None')
                text_file.write('\n'+str(y) + "\t" + 'None')


#get_list("trackthis1","tracking_column")
#evaluate_excel("trackthis1","tracking_column","output3.txt")
```

Comment: When you write a question,  the page shows a preview.  You should use it.

Comment: `tracking_column` is defined outside your code. But probably coming from `input` which now returns a string...

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the following

```
 for x in tracklist:
            y = x
            a,b,c = evaluate(x)
            if a != "":
                text_file.write('\n'+str(y) + "\t" +str(a)+"\t"+str(b) + "\t" + str(c)+'\t')
                print(str(y) + "\t" +str(a)+"\t"+str(b) + "\t" + str(c)+'\t')
```

to:

```
for x in tracklist:
            y = int(x)
            a,b,c = evaluate(x)
            if a != "":
                text_file.write('\n'+str(y) + "\t" +str(a)+"\t"+str(b) + "\t" + str(c)+'\t')
                print(str(y) + "\t" +str(a)+"\t"+str(b) + "\t" + str(c)+'\t')
```

not sure if this will work or not, but I know that python 3 can be a pain about stuff. you also have to remember not all modules work like they should in 3 since its "newer" so that could also be you problem